# Jquery POST 500 Internal Error ]when trying to submit a Wufoo form

Tags: ajax, post, wufoo

I am trying to submit a wufoo form via AJAX. I am using jQuery $.post to achieve this and am getting a 500 (Internal Server Error) returned back from the php script. The javascript code is:

```
$('form#form20').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('form_handler.php', $('form#form20').serialize(), function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

The php code from the form_handler.php file is:

```
<?php  
    if (count($_POST) > 0) {
        $fieldErrors = initAPI($root);
    }
    $wufoo_query_vals = array(
        'w_api_key' => 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
        'w_form' => 'connect-with-us',
        '1' => $_POST['Field1'],
        '2' => $_POST['Field2'],
        '3' => $_POST['Field3'],
        '4' => $_POST['Field4'],
        '5' => $_POST['Field5'],
        '11' => $_POST['Field11'],
        '14' => $_POST['Field14'],
        '13' => $_POST['Field13'],
        '8' => $_POST['Field8'],
        '9' => $_POST['Field9']
    );

    foreach($wufoo_query_vals as $key => $value) {
        $request .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
    }
    $request = substr($request, 0, -1);
    $ch = curl_init("http://defineyouredge.wufoo.com/api/insert/"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $response;  
?>
```

I have removed the API key for obvious reasons, but I do have it correctly entered in the actual code. Also, I have not completed the functionality for handling the response. Currently, just logging the the response to the console for testing.

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Which part of "internal server error" is hard to understand?

Comment: I just don't understand why it is not processing the form data and giving me a successful response.

Comment: Showing your _client's_ code is not going to help anyone (except _possibly_ the author of the server code) figure out why an **internal error in the server** occurs. There seem to be some fundamental misunderstanding going on if you think an **internal server error** is something that you as a _user_ of the service is responsible for, or even theoretically able to, diagnose or avoid.